# When was the Demonic Statue of the Outer Path actually sealed into the moon?

Tags: naruto

When was the Demonic Statue of the Outer Path actually sealed into the moon?

Older/Earlier parts of manga:
In the older version of the manga, before Kaguya was revived in the manga, it was said that Hagoromo sealed the Ten-Tails' husk (Demonic Statue of the Outer Path) singlehandedly into the moon while he was nearing his death.

Newer/Later parts of manga:
But when Kaguya came back, Black Zetsu said that the Demonic Statue of the Outer Path was sealed into the moon after the Ten-Tails was defeated by Hagoromo and his younger twin brother, Hamura.

Which version is correct? 
If the newer/later parts of manga is correct, does that mean that Hagoromo was never the jinchuriki of the Ten-Tails, as the Ten-Tails is composed of the Demonic Statue of the Outer Path and the One-Tail to Nine-Tails?